# jQuery - can you have multiple .on attached to specific elements

Tags: jquery

Can I have multiple instances as per below, or should I have one, but identify what triggers the event and process accordingly?

```
$('.someClass')
    .on("keydown","[id*=txtAccountID],[id*=txtLinkedToAccountID]...
$('.someClass')
    .on("keydown","[id*=txtDateDB],[id*=txtDateHuman]...
```

OR

```
$('.someClass')
    .on("keydown","[id*=txtAccountID],[id*=txtLinkedToAccountID],[id*=txtDateDB],[id*=txtDateHuman]...

resID = $(this).prop("id");

if (resID = "XYZ" ) {
    //do account related stuff
else if (resID = "ABC"  ) {
    //do date related stuff
}
```

Comment: Won't the keydown be triggering the event?

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully more clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. according to the [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc):

> If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in
>   the order in which they were bound

**EDIT**
This qoute is from the `.bind` documentation but relevant for `.on` as well.
You can see the same scenario in the `.on` [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data) as well.

> As of jQuery 1.4, the same event handler can be bound to an element
>   multiple times.

Example:

```js
$('#parent').on('click','.child, .child3', function(e){ console.log("Click #1 for - " + e.target.innerText)})
$('#parent').on('click','.child, .child3', function(e){ console.log("Click #2 for - " + e.target.innerText)})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child child1">
  child 1 ( click me!)
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    child 2 ( click me!)
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
  child 3 ( click me!)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange, as I've tried adding two .on ("keyup".. events (slightly different selectors) and the jQuery doesn't run at all.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: I was looking at two separate events, both on keyup/down etc, but on different selectors as the processing code is substantially different.  It's not a major issue, it's not working to have that, so I'll have one that covers all required electors and handle requests accordingly.

Comment: I actually managed to get it to work. I had a ';' after the first, which was screwing it up.

Answer (score 1):

**You can bind as many event handlers as you want to your element**

```js
$(function(){
  var reset = $("#reset");
  var run1   = $("#run1");
  var run2   = $("#run2");
  var target = $("#target");
  var defaultText ="Click the buttons To see multiple handlers evaluated in the order they were bound";
  
  reset.click(rst);
  
  var log = $("#data");
  
  function rst(ev){
  target.text("Event Triggered by "+ev.target.id);
  log.text(defaultText);
  }
  function clear(ev){
  target.text("Event Triggered by "+ev.target.id);
  log.text("");
  }
  function one(ev){
  target.text("Event Triggered by "+ev.target.id);
  $('<p>One</p>').appendTo(log);
  }
  
  function two(ev){
  target.text("Event Triggered by "+ev.target.id);
$('<p>Two</p>').appendTo(log);
}
function three(ev){
target.text("Event Triggered by "+ev.target.id);
$('<p>Three</p>').appendTo(log);
}
  run1.click(clear)
  .click(one)
  .click(two)
  .click(three);
  run2.click(clear)
  .click(one)
  .click(two)
  .click(three);
  });
```

```css
.fun {
width:100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="fun" id="run1">Run - 1</button>
<button class="fun" id="run2">Run - 2</button>
<button class="fun" id="reset">Reset</button>
<div id="target"></div>
<div id="data">
Click the buttons
To see multiple handlers
evaluated in the order 
they were bound
</div>
```